# c ordered linked list logic error

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a program that maintains an ordered linked list. The problem I'm having is that when I use a function that displays all the contents of the list, only the last entry shows up. I would like your help in figuring out where the logic error is.

For example, if I use the insert method to enter the following keys and data

```
1 "test"
2 "more tests"
```

then I use the dumplist function, here's the output:
`2 "more tests"`

Here's the main program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list_funcs.h"

int main(void) {

    struct data_node *first=NULL, *new_node, *ptr;
    char input = 't';


    do {    
            int tempKey;
            char s[25];
            printf("Enter list command (+-flx):  ");
            scanf("%c", &input);
            printf("%c detected", input); 
            //insterting data into the list
            if (input=='+') {
                printf(" \n Enter key data :  ");
                scanf("%d", &tempKey);
                printf("\n %d detected ", tempKey); 
                printf("\n Enter the string to be stored:  ");
                scanf("%s", s);
                printf("\n You entered %s  ", s); 
                ptr=insert(&first, tempKey);
                first = ptr;
                strcpy(ptr->name, s);

            }
            //finding in the list
            if (input == 'f') {
                printf("\n Enter key data :  ");
                scanf("%d", &tempKey);
                printf("\n %d detected ", tempKey);
                ptr=find_node(first, tempKey);
                dump_node(ptr);

            }
            //printing list
            if (input == 'l') {
                dump_list(first);               

            }
            //deletion
            if (input == '-') {
                printf("Enter key data :  ");
                scanf("%d", &tempKey);
                printf(" \n  %d detected ", tempKey);
                delete(&first, tempKey);
            }

    } while (input!='x');
    printf("Goodbye the program has ended!");



return 0;

}
```

and here are the functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list_funcs.h"
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem) {


    struct data_node *new_node, *prev, *current;
    current=*p_first;
    while (current != NULL && elem > current->data) {
        prev=current;
        current=current->next;
    } /* end while */
/* current now points to position *before* which we need to insert */
    new_node = (struct data_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));
    new_node->data=elem;

    new_node->next=current;
    if ( current == *p_first ) /* insert before 1st element */
        *p_first=new_node; 
    else                       /* now insert before current */
        prev->next=new_node;
/* end if current == *p_first */
    return new_node;
};

struct data_node * find_node (struct data_node *p, int elem) {
while (p != NULL) {
   if ( elem == p->data )
      return p;
   p=p->next;
   } /* end while */
}; /* end find_node */

void dump_node (struct data_node *current) {
printf("Dumping node: ");
if (current != NULL)
   printf("%s: %d\n", current->name, current->data);
}; /* end dump_list */


void dump_list (struct data_node *current) {
    printf("List dump:\n");
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", current->name, current->data);
        current=current->next;
    } /* end while */
    printf("\n");
}; /* end dump_list */

int delete (struct data_node **p_first, int elem) {
    int retval = 0;
    struct data_node *current, *prev;
    current=*p_first;
    while (current != NULL && elem != current->data ) {
        prev=current;
        current=current->next;
   }
    if (current == NULL) /* element not found */
        return retval;
/* current now points to node to delete */
    if ( current == *p_first ) /* delete 1st node */
        *p_first = (*p_first)->next;
    else  /* link previous to next thus skipping over node to delete */
        prev->next=current->next;
        free(current);
        retval=1;
    return retval;
}; /* end delete */
```

edited to add the header file

```
#define STRINGMAX 25

struct data_node {
  char name [STRINGMAX];
  int data;
  struct data_node *next;
  };



struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **, int);
struct data_node * find_node (struct data_node *, int);
void dump_list (struct data_node *); 
int delete (struct data_node **, int);
void dump_node (struct data_node *);
```

Comment: Note that the semicolon after the close brace of a function is an empty declaration of a non-existent variable, or thereabouts.  It is not required and compilers set to fussy will tell you about it. If your compiler isn't warning you about that, you haven't got it being fussy enough.  You need all the help it can give.  Remember: at this stage in your career, your compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the header too; otherwise we have to reverse engineer it.  Not dreadfully hard, but harder than it needs to be.

Comment: added the header code as well and thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
printf("\n You entered %s  ", s); 
ptr=insert(&first, tempKey);
first = ptr;
```

Your function carefully updated `first` to point to the head of the list, but you then overwrote it with the newly inserted key.  If you enter the data in reverse order, all is fine.  If you do it in forwards order, you keep throwing away the head of the list.

Drop the assignment: <s>`first = ptr;`</s>.

Also, your `insert` function should be passed `s` as a parameter and it should do the copy into `ptr->name`.

#### Working code

```
//#include "list_funcs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef LIST_FUNCS_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_FUNCS_H_INCLUDED

#define STRINGMAX 25

struct data_node
{
    char name[STRINGMAX];
    int data;
    struct data_node *next;
};

struct data_node *insert(struct data_node **, int, char *);
struct data_node *find_node(struct data_node *, int);
void dump_list(struct data_node *);
int delete(struct data_node **, int);
void dump_node(struct data_node *);

#endif

int main(void)
{
    struct data_node *first = NULL, *ptr;
    char input = 't';

    do
    {
        int tempKey;
        char s[STRINGMAX];
        printf("Enter list command (+-flx):  ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        printf("%c detected\n", input);

        if (input == '+')
        {
            printf(" \n Enter key data :  ");
            scanf("%d", &tempKey);
            printf("\n %d detected ", tempKey);
            printf("\n Enter the string to be stored:  ");
            scanf("%s", s);
            printf("\n You entered [%s]\n", s);
            ptr = insert(&first, tempKey, s);
            //first = ptr;
        }
        else if (input == 'f')
        {
            printf("\n Enter key data :  ");
            scanf("%d", &tempKey);
            printf("\n %d detected\n", tempKey);
            ptr = find_node(first, tempKey);
            dump_node(ptr);
        }
        else if (input == 'l')
        {
            dump_list(first);
        }
        else if (input == '-')
        {
            printf("Enter key data :  ");
            scanf("%d", &tempKey);
            printf(" \n  %d detected ", tempKey);
            delete(&first, tempKey);
        }
    } while (input != 'x');

    printf("Goodbye the program has ended!\n");
    return 0;
}

struct data_node *insert(struct data_node **p_first, int elem, char *str)
{
    struct data_node *new_node, *prev = 0, *current;
    current = *p_first;
    while (current != NULL && elem > current->data)
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    dump_node(current);
    dump_node(prev);

    new_node = (struct data_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));
    new_node->data = elem;
    strcpy(new_node->name, str);
    new_node->next = current;

    if (current == *p_first)
        *p_first = new_node;
    else
        prev->next = new_node;

    dump_node(*p_first);
    dump_node(new_node);
    return new_node;
}

struct data_node *find_node(struct data_node *p, int elem)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (elem == p->data)
            return p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return p;
}

void dump_node(struct data_node *current)
{
    printf("Dumping node %p: ", (void *)current);
    if (current != NULL)
        printf("%s: %d (%p)", current->name, current->data, current->next);
    putchar('\n');
}

void dump_list(struct data_node *current)
{
    printf("List dump:\n");
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s: %d\n", current->name, current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int delete(struct data_node **p_first, int elem)
{
    int retval = 0;
    struct data_node *current, *prev;
    current = *p_first;
    while (current != NULL && elem != current->data)
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current == NULL)
        return retval;

    if (current == *p_first)
        *p_first = (*p_first)->next;
    else
        prev->next = current->next;
    free(current);
    retval = 1;
    return retval;
}
```

(I've not tested delete; the find and list functions work OK, though they now print more information than they did before.)